# Lambda Expression for OrderBy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

```
///  Model
public class MenuModels
{
    public Int32 MenuId { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public Int32 MenuLevel { get; set; }
    public Int32 MenuParent { get; set; }
    public string MenuUrl { get; set; }
}

///    In my Controller I have this code
Menus = menuRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(y=>y.menu_id+y.menu_parent+y.menu_level).ToList()
```

I want to get all the menus in ascending order by sum of 3 fields(id,parentId,level).

or else concatenation of 2 fields(id,parentId)

```
menuRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(y=>int.parse(y.menu_id.ToString+y.menu_parent.ToString)).ToList()
```

Basically im creating a MENU Create Controller in that i have a dropdownlist that fills the all the menus, but i want to fill menus in dropdown like

```
Home
--submenu1
--submenu2
Contact
--submenu1
--submenu2
```

for this i have written code below

```
        var menuModel = new MenuModels()
        {
            Menus = menuRepository.GetAll().ToList().Select(x =>
                           {
                               var level = x.menu_level;
                               return (level == 0)
                                          ? new SelectListItem {Text = x.menu_name, Value = x.menu_id.ToString()}
                                          : new SelectListItem {Text = "-- "+x.menu_name, Value = x.menu_id.ToString()};
                           })
         };
        return View(menuModel);
```

But this doesn't give me what im expecting and i know why, 
in database i have table like

```
id   level   parent   name
---------------------------
1    0       0        Home
2    0       0        About
3    1       1        submenu1
4    1       1        submenu2
5    1       2        submenu1
```

i made sql query for this to get better understanding my problem

```
select *,( Convert(nvarchar(50),(case when menu_parent=0 then menu_id else menu_parent end))  + '' +  Convert(nvarchar (50),(menu_parent)))
 as Sort from menu order by Sort,menu_id
```

this query results like

```
id   level   parent   name      Sort
------------------------------------
1    0       0        Home       10
3    1       1        submenu1   11
4    1       1        submenu2   11
2    0       0        Abount     20
5    1       2        submenu1   22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
menuRepository.GetAll().
        select(y= new MenuDatastructure() 
        {
            //rest of the properties like menuid,menuName etc,
            sortColumn = //concat the fields to get sort column like 10,11,11,20,22
        }
        ).OrderBy(y=>y.sortColumn).ToList()
```

Comment: see by doin' this, first it'll sort all by menu_id and then menu_parent and so on, i dont want this, i want the menus to be sorted like 1st parent then its child..

Comment: i guess you didnt get my question, im having a menuTable which contains all parent and child menus, now when displaying all these menus in a dropdown, i want to display like parent and then all its child parent2 and then all its childs.. i edited my question

Comment: Updated the answer, please test

Comment: yep now you got my point.. thanx man.. i was doin' this way but i got stuck at concatating 2 integer in `Sort` variable. Now my problem solved..